# Difference between using std::vector and include<vector>

Tags: c++, include

I've noticed that some people prefer

```
#include <vector>
```

and others prefer

```
using std::vector;
```

Is there a difference? I couldn't find a post on this on SO.

Changing from one to another in my code procures no less/additional errors.

Thank you

Comment: What makes you think that this is [tag:c]?

Comment: I don't understand. This would be c++

Comment: Then why did you tag with [tag:c]?

Comment: You might want to start by reading a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) - you can't really learn a programming language by guess-work.

Comment: I made a mistake, my apologies. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: I've noticed some people live in houses and some people check their mailbox. Which is better? I've tried both and I didn't see a big difference.

Answer (score 1):

`#include <vector>` is a must when you use `vector`.

`using std::vector;` is optional as this saves you from typing `std::` when declaring a vector for example.

```
vector<int> v;         // no need  prefix std::
```

Answer (score 1):

These are related to some degree, but neither replaces the other.

`#include <vector>`

This makes a declaration of `vector` visible, so you can define objects of type `vector<T>` (for some type `T`), define functions that take a `vector` by value, return a vector by value, etc.

`using std::vector;`

This makes the declaration of `vector` visible without your having to qualify it with the name of the namespace in which it resides (`std`) so, for example, to define a `vector` of `int`s, you can use:

```
vector<int> x;
```

...instead of:

```
std::vector<int> x;
```

...as you need to when you've just done the `#include <vector>` without the `using` declaration.